# Connection between two collections in azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I have two collections in Azure.

Collection A
Collection B

In collection A, there are few scripts say script 1 and in collection B there are scripts say script 2

I need to find a trigger mechanism such that

- when we execute the script 2 in collection B
  then script 1 should execute in Collection A
- with the artifact provided by Collection B

Have [looked into Microsoft Azure pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#triggers).

but didn't find any solutions

Comment: Azure DevOps Server I suppose? if you're talking about collections? There isn't really a lot of support for cross collection and cross organization triggers in Azure Pipelines. You'd end up having to add specific steps in your pipeline to trigger these builds and you'll need access tokens in order to authenticate these steps. The `az devops` cli extension would be an easy way to go about this.

Comment: There are a few extensions in the marketplace that support similar scenario's. I don't have a lot of experience with them, as your scenario is somewhat uncommon. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geeklearningio.gl-vsts-tasks-inception

You could also look into the webhooks features and tie in a small Azure Function to act when the webhook triggers.

Comment: Check out the `az devops` extension specifically the `az pipelines run` subcommand. And the `az pipelines runs artifact download` subcommand. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/service-page/azure%20pipelines?view=azure-cli-latest